# How to display raw sql query count value in django rest api

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-responses

The Group by count value is not showing rest api call but group by working perfectly 
This is my views.py file

```
class TestList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Test.objects.raw('SELECT  1 as id ,v1 ,COUNT(*)  FROM posts_test GROUP BY v1 order by count(*) desc  LIMIT 10')
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        # the serializer didn't take my RawQuerySet, so made it into a list
        serializer = TestSerializer(list(queryset), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

OutPut :

```
[{"v1":"fg","v2":"fg","v3":"fg"},
 {"v1":"nn","v2":"fg","v3":"fg"}, 
 {"v1":"kk","v2":"fg","v3":"fg"}]
```

But I want like this :

```
[{"v1":"fg","v2":"fg","v3":"fg","count":20,},
 {"v1":"nn","v2":"fg","v3":"fg","count":15,},
 {"v1":"kk","v2":"fg","v3":"fg","count":10,}]
```

Comment: you need to add the `count` to your serializer.

Comment: @BearBrown This is my Serializer                                                                                    '''class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 #v1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
 #count = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

 class Meta:
  fields = ('v1', 'v2','v3','count',)
  model = models.Test'''                                                                             
      after that i got error like this  ->Field name `count` is not valid for model `Test`.